# How to write features on cucumber tests without duplicating scenarios?

Tags: cucumber

I am working with bdd testing using cucumber (https://cucumber.io) and want to test a feature with two rest services.

How do I write this feature file contains x scenarios without duplicating each scenario for a feature file for each rest service?

Normally, my feature files starts with a background (being what rest service to use) followed by each scenario the feature supports (see example). I want to be able to run each scenario in the file with a different background...

Example:

```
Background:
Given a rest service `<some rest service>`

Scenario: should perform x
When performing `x`
Then `y`

Scenario: should feil with z
When performing `z`
Then http status should be `400`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your scenarios are too generic and use too many technical terms, like "http status" and "rest service". None of the steps are phrased using the business language.

Either rephrase your steps to use the same language the business uses or don't use cucumber. Maybe these tests are better off as plain unit test-style tests written in the same language the REST services are written in.

If you want to practice behavior driven development you will need to learn the basics. I recommend reading [BDD 101: Introducing BDD](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/25/bdd-101-introducing-bdd/) as a starting point.